# Maximum Element in a Binary Tree (Error while trying root.getData())

Tags: java, tree, max, binary-tree, element

I created a binary tree using templates. I entered integer values for all the nodes and I want to find the maximum element in the Binary Tree.

Here is the implementation:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    private T data;
    BinaryTreeNode right;
    BinaryTreeNode left;

    public BinaryTreeNode(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.right = null;
        this.left = null;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public int findMax(BinaryTreeNode root){
        int max= 0;
        if(root==null){
            return 0;
        } else {
            int left= findMax(root.left);
            int right= findMax(root.right);

            max= Math.max(left,right);
            if(max> root.getData()){
                max= root.getData();
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> incompatible types: required int found java.lang.Object.

I wrote this in the modified version:

```
int data= Integer.valueOf((String)root.getData());
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know by which rules you created the binary tree, but usually one works with a "binary search tree" where the nodes are ordered by some criterion. At each node you would have smaller nodes are in th left subtree and larger nodes in the right. To find the maximum you would then just go right until there is no right child.

Comment: @Henry the question says nothing about binary search tree, so I'm assuming it's an arbitrary (not sorted) binary tree.

Comment: @Eran yes, but since it does not make much sense to have a binary tree just for the sake of it I wondered if this was really intended.

Answer (score 0):

`root.getData()` has a generic type `T`. This means you can't assume it will be an `Integer`, you can't determine which of two nodes has a higher value using `Math.max()` and `findMax()` should return `T`, not an `int`.

In order to find the max element, you must either require that `T extends Comparable<T>`, which will allow you to compare the data of two `BinaryTreeNode`s using `compareTo()`, or you should pass a `Comparator<T>` instance to the constructor of your tree, which will allow you to compare the data of `BinaryTreeNode`s using `compare()`.

You must also avoid using the raw type `BinaryTreeNode`. Replace it will `BinaryTreeNode<T>` in all your methods. Otherwise, method call such as `root.getData()` will return an `Object` instead of `T`.

Using `Comparable`:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    ...

    public T findMax(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {
        T max = null;
        if(root == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            T left = findMax(root.left);
            T right = findMax(root.right);

            max = left.compareTo(right) <= 0 ? right : left;
            if(max.compareTo(root.getData()) < 0) {
                max = root.getData();
            }
            return max;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```